# Nested for loop and filter query with parent field does not work with Microsoft flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

I am new to Microsoft dynamics & flow, I have following schema

```
Course
  Id - Primary key
  Title - Title of the course
  Date - Course date field

Participant
   Id - Primary key
   CourseId - Course id foreign key(From Course relation)
```

**First Try**

I would like to filter based on date so I use List records action and I just loop through each course to get participants(`List records action`) and then I need to again loop through participants so that I need to send them email about the course. The problem is nested loop is not supported.

**Alternate tryout**

Instead of querying Course, I use List records action to get all the participants with course date in Course. This is just a join and where condition. But this also doesn't help.
This is the error I am getting **The Property (0) is not a primary key of the related entity**

In Filter Query I have `Course/Date gt @{utcNow()}` which throws above error but `course/Id` eq 12-321-23123-12332` works but useless.

Anything else I can tryout?

Comment: why retrieveing of `Participants` doesn't helped?

Comment: @ASpirin updated the question with error message retrieving `Participants`

Answer (score 0):

This case is mentioned in a [limitations list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt628816.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_246253), but, for some reasons, MSDN has another error message for the same case

> Can't filter queries based on the value of a single-valued navigation property
>   "message": "The query node (0) is not supported",

As an alternative try to use [FetchXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607533.aspx#bkmk_useFetchXML) for this specific case